# How do I put Logo image in the center, keeping Login link on the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code for the header. I want to keep the Login in the nav bar, and I want to center the Logo. Can you help me? Thank you!

```
<header>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container" style="overflow: auto; ">
<img src="" style="float: none; " alt="logo" /><!--Logo-->
<ul class="nav pull-right" style="float: left;">
<li>
<a style="color:#ffffff;"><p><u>Login</u></p></a>   
</li>
</ul>
</div>  
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: I would set width and height to the image and center it using flex:   
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS Positioning. Make your parent element `relative` and image `absolute`. And then center the image using `transform` property.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container" style="overflow: auto; ">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" style="float: none; " alt="logo" /><!--Logo-->
<ul class="nav pull-right" style="float: left;">
<li>
<a><p><u>Login</u></p></a>   
</li>
</ul>
</div>  
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ElizabethCruz It's my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged Twitter-Bootstrap so why not use the twitter-bootstrap class `.navbar-brand`?

You could add it like this

```
<header>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
     <a class="navbar-brand">Logo</a>
      <div class="container" style="overflow: auto; ">
          <ul class="nav pull-right" style="float: left;">
            <li>
              <a id="login"><p><u>Login</u></p></a>   
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Then in your custom CSS you could use to position it center.

```
 .navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

X3 methods to achieve this demonstrated in the snippet below.

**1.** Method 1: `display: inline-block; text-align: center`
**2.** Method 2: `display: block; margin: auto;`
**3.** Method 3: `position: absolute` (on un-ordered list)
**4.** Method 4: `position: absolute` (on logo)

```css
/* Method 1 */
#method-one .navbar-fixed-top {
    background: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

#method-one .navbar-fixed-top img {
    display: inline-block;
}

#method-one .navbar-fixed-top .container {
    text-align: center;
}

/* Method 2 */
#method-two .navbar-fixed-top {
    background: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

#method-two .navbar-fixed-top img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

#method-two .navbar-fixed-top .container {
    text-align: center;
}

/* Method 3 */
#method-three .navbar-fixed-top {
    background: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

#method-three .navbar-fixed-top img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

#method-three .navbar-fixed-top .container {
    text-align: center;
}

#method-three ul.nav.pull-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    float: none;
    top: 10px;
}

/* Method 4 */
#method-four .navbar-fixed-top {
    background: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 120px;
}

#method-four .navbar-fixed-top img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#method-four .navbar-fixed-top .container {
    text-align: center;
}

#method-four ul.nav.pull-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    float: none;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header id="method-one">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container" style="overflow: auto; ">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97100&w=200&h=100" style="float: none; " alt="logo" />
        <!--Logo-->
        <ul class="nav pull-right" style="float: right;">
          <li>
            <a style="color:#ffffff;">
              <p><u>Login</u>
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<hr>
<header id="method-two">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container" style="overflow: auto; ">
        <ul class="nav pull-right" style="float: right;">
          <li>
            <a style="color:#ffffff;">
              <p><u>Login</u>
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97100&w=200&h=100" style="float: none; " alt="logo" />
        <!--Logo-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<hr>
<header id="method-three">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container" style="overflow: auto; ">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97100&w=200&h=100" style="float: none; " alt="logo" />
        <!--Logo-->
        <ul class="nav pull-right" style="float: right;">
          <li>
            <a style="color:#ffffff;">
              <p><u>Login</u>
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<hr>
<header id="method-four">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container" style="overflow: auto; ">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97100&w=200&h=100" style="float: none; " alt="logo" />
        <!--Logo-->
        <ul class="nav pull-right" style="float: right;">
          <li>
            <a style="color:#ffffff;">
              <p><u>Login</u>
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```